# child element in front of all the other elements outside the parent, css

Tags: css

I want a child element to be in front of the element below the parent element without making the parent of the child to be in front of the other element. Is that possible or is there a better solution for this?

The slider is supposed to cover the light blue menu but not the text :)

My Code:

```css
ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  background: #00FFFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00FFBB;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 110px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #00CFCF;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li:nth-child(1).active~.slide {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

ul li:nth-child(2).active~.slide {
  left: 110px;
  opacity: 1;
}

ul li:nth-child(3).active~.slide {
  left: 220px;
  opacity: 1;
}

ul li:nth-child(4).active~.slide {
  left: 330px;
  opacity: 1;
}

ul li:nth-child(5).active~.slide {
  left: 440px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class=""><a href="#">constant</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">blink</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">rainbow</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">stack-led</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">pong</a></li>
  <li class="slide"></li>
</ul>
```

I appreciate your help.

I've tried to use z-index but nope, does not work. I wanted the child of a parent to be in front of the other element below the parent.

Comment: So you want the `.slider` element to be between the light-blue background and the black text, is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's my wish.

Comment: like `ul a{position:relative}`? bc otherwise the `z-index:1` has no effect?